# Computing intersection of vector spaces spanned by two lists

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, computer-algebra-systems

Assume that I'm given two lists of vectors $l_1$ and $l_2$, where all the vectors have equal dimension. I want to compute a basis for the intersection of their spans. What is the easiest setup for computing this in a computer algebra system? I remember there being some way of computing this using augmented matrices, where $l_1$ forms one part $l_2$ another and then adding something and row reducing and picking up certain columns.

To be clear, I know how to set this up mathematically, but I'm looking for a way of doing it that won't require very much code. The reason I want this is that it looks like this is not an operation that's built into Mathematica.

Comment: In Maple, it's simply **LinearAlgebra:-IntersectionBasis**.

Comment: One way would be to utilize the fact the taking the orthogonal complement takes intersection to sum (and that summing of subspaces given by bases is easier). So find bases for the orthogonal complements of the spans of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ by solving the homogeneous systems. Put the bases of the solution spaces together and row reduce. Take the dual again and rejoice.

Comment: Oh, and you may consider asking this at [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) if that's the CAS you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

There are many systems capable of doing this. In [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) (which is distributed freely under GPL) you may do, for example, the following:

```
gap> V:= VectorSpace( Rationals, [ [ 1, 2, 7 ], [ 1/2, 1/3, 5 ] ] );;
gap> W:= VectorSpace( Rationals, [ [ 1, 3, 5 ], [ 1/3, 1/2, 7 ] ] );;
gap> H:=Intersection(V,W);                                            
<vector space of dimension 1 over Rationals>
gap> b:=Basis(H);
SemiEchelonBasis( <vector space of dimension 1 over Rationals>, 
[ [ 1, 306/101, 473/101 ] ] )
gap> AsList(b);
[ [ 1, 306/101, 473/101 ] ]
```

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood the question which was about how to program this in Mathematica. Anyhow, if you will decide that it's better to use an existing solution that to implement your own, there is an interface between Mathematica and GAP called [SCSCP4Mathematica](http://www.risc.jku.at/people/kbosa/science/).

Comment: P.S. If one is interested in the details of GAP implementation, it uses Zassenhaus' algorithm to compute bases for the sum and the intersection of spaces generated by the rows of two matrices. The implementation can be traced in `Intersection2` from `lib/vspc.gi` and `SumIntersectionMat` from `lib/matrix.gi`.